# How do I truncate the significand of a floating point number to an arbitrary precision in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I would like to introduce some artificial precision loss into two numbers being compared to smooth out minor rounding errors so that I don't have to use the `Math.abs(x - y) < eps` idiom in every comparison involving `x` and `y`.

Essentially, I want something that behaves similarly to down-casting a `double` to a `float` and then up-casting it back to a `double`, except I want to also preserve very large and very small exponents and I want some control over the number of significand bits preserved.

Given the following function that produces the binary representation of the significand of a 64-bit IEEE 754 number:

```java
public static String significand(double d) {
    int SIGN_WIDTH = 1;
    int EXP_WIDTH = 11;
    int SIGNIFICAND_WIDTH = 53;
    String s = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d))).replace(' ', '0');
    return s.substring(0 + SIGN_WIDTH, 0 + SIGN_WIDTH + EXP_WIDTH);
}
```

I want a function `reducePrecision(double x, int bits)` that reduces the precision of the significand of a `double` such that:

```java
significand(reducePrecision(x, bits)).substring(bits).equals(String.format("%0" + (52 - bits) + "d", 0))
```

In other words, every bit after the `bits`-most significant bit in the significand of `reducePrecision(x, bits)` should be 0, while the `bits`-most significant bits in the significand of `reducePrecision(x, bits)` should reasonably approximate the `bits`-most signicant bits in the significand of `x`.

Comment: (a) This does not “smooth out” rounding errors; it makes them bigger. This is not a good way to deal with rounding errors in floating-point operations. (b) Ways to round a floating-point number to a specific numbers of bits in the significand are already known. We had a question dealing with this recently, for which I pointed out [the Veltkamp-Dekker split algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48698954/298225).

Comment: Agreed, reducing precision will always lead to larger errors. A better description of the objective would be to "specify an arbitrary binary discretization of floating point numbers".

Comment: I do now see that this question is a duplicate of a fairly common question though. I need to work on my Google-fu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `x` is the number you wish to reduce the precision of and `bits` is the number of significant bits you wish to retain.

When `bits` is sufficiently large and the order of magnitude of `x` is sufficiently close to 0, then `x * (1L << (bits - Math.getExponent(x)))` will scale `x` so that the bits that need to be removed will appear in the fractional component (after the radix point) while the bits that will be retained will appear in the integer component (before the radix point). You can then round this to remove the fractional component and then divide the rounded number by `(1L << (bits - Math.getExponent(x)))` to restore the order of magnitude of `x`, i.e.:

```java
public static double reducePrecision(double x, int bits) {
    int exponent = bits - Math.getExponent(x);
    return Math.round(x * (1L << exponent)) / (1L << exponent);
}
```

However, `(1L << exponent)` will break down when `Math.getExponent(x) > bits || Math.getExponent(x) < bits - 62`. The solution is to use `Math.pow(2, exponent)` (or the fast `pow2(exponent)` implementation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48725904/444402)) to calculate a fractional, or a very large, power of 2, i.e.:

```java
public static double reducePrecision(double x, int bits) {
    int exponent = bits - Math.getExponent(x);
    return Math.round(x * Math.pow(2, exponent)) * Math.pow(2, -exponent);
}
```

However, `Math.pow(2, exponent)` will break down as `exponent` approaches -1074 or +1023. The solution is to use `Math.scalb(x, exponent)` so that the power of 2 doesn't have to be explicitly calculated, i.e.:

```java
public static double reducePrecision(double x, int bits) {
    int exponent = bits - Math.getExponent(x);
    return Math.scalb(Math.round(Math.scalb(x, exponent)), -exponent);
}
```

However, `Math.round(y)` returns a `long` so it does not preserve `Infinity`, `NaN`, and cases where `Math.abs(x) > Long.MAX_VALUE / Math.pow(2, exponent)`. Furthermore, `Math.round(y)` always rounds ties to positive infinity (e.g. `Math.round(0.5) == 1 && Math.round(1.5) == 2`). The solution is to use `Math.rint(y)` to receive a `double` and preserve the unbiased IEEE 754 round-to-nearest, ties-to-even rule (e.g. `Math.rint(0.5) == 0.0 && Math.rint(1.5) == 2.0`), i.e.:

```java
public static double reducePrecision(double x, int bits) {
    int exponent = bits - Math.getExponent(x);
    return Math.scalb(Math.rint(Math.scalb(x, exponent)), -exponent);
}
```

Finally, here is a unit test confirming our expectations:

```java
public static String decompose(double d) {
    int SIGN_WIDTH = 1;
    int EXP_WIDTH = 11;
    int SIGNIFICAND_WIDTH = 53;
    String s = String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d))).replace(' ', '0');
    return s.substring(0, 0 + SIGN_WIDTH) + " "
            + s.substring(0 + SIGN_WIDTH, 0 + SIGN_WIDTH + EXP_WIDTH) + " "
            + s.substring(0 + SIGN_WIDTH + EXP_WIDTH, 0 + SIGN_WIDTH + EXP_WIDTH + SIGNIFICAND_WIDTH - 1);
}

public static void test() {
    // Use a fixed seed so the generated numbers are reproducible.
    java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random(0);

    // Generate a floating point number that makes use of its full 52 bits of significand precision.
    double a = r.nextDouble() * 100;
    System.out.println(decompose(a) + " " + a);
    Assert.assertFalse(decompose(a).split(" ")[2].substring(23).equals(String.format("%0" + (52 - 23) + "d", 0)));

    // Cast the double to a float to produce a "ground truth" of precision loss to compare against.
    double b = (float) a;
    System.out.println(decompose(b) + " " + b);
    Assert.assertTrue(decompose(b).split(" ")[2].substring(23).equals(String.format("%0" + (52 - 23) + "d", 0)));
    // 32-bit float has a 23 bit significand, so c's bit pattern should be identical to b's bit pattern.
    double c = reducePrecision(a, 23);
    System.out.println(decompose(c) + " " + c);
    Assert.assertTrue(b == c);

    // 23rd-most significant bit in c is 1, so rounding it to the 22nd-most significant bit requires breaking a tie.
    // Since 22nd-most significant bit in c is 0, d will be rounded down so that its 22nd-most significant bit remains 0.
    double d = reducePrecision(c, 22);
    System.out.println(decompose(d) + " " + d);
    Assert.assertTrue(decompose(d).split(" ")[2].substring(22).equals(String.format("%0" + (52 - 22) + "d", 0)));
    Assert.assertTrue(decompose(c).split(" ")[2].charAt(22) == '1' && decompose(c).split(" ")[2].charAt(21) == '0');
    Assert.assertTrue(decompose(d).split(" ")[2].charAt(21) == '0');
    // 21st-most significant bit in d is 1, so rounding it to the 20th-most significant bit requires breaking a tie.
    // Since 20th-most significant bit in d is 1, e will be rounded up so that its 20th-most significant bit becomes 0.
    double e = reducePrecision(c, 20);
    System.out.println(decompose(e) + " " + e);
    Assert.assertTrue(decompose(e).split(" ")[2].substring(20).equals(String.format("%0" + (52 - 20) + "d", 0)));
    Assert.assertTrue(decompose(d).split(" ")[2].charAt(20) == '1' && decompose(d).split(" ")[2].charAt(19) == '1');
    Assert.assertTrue(decompose(e).split(" ")[2].charAt(19) == '0');

    // Reduce the precision of a number close to the largest normal number.
    double f = reducePrecision(a * 0x1p+1017, 23);
    System.out.println(decompose(f) + " " + f);
    // Reduce the precision of a number close to the smallest normal number.
    double g = reducePrecision(a * 0x1p-1028, 23);
    System.out.println(decompose(g) + " " + g);
    // Reduce the precision of a number close to the smallest subnormal number.
    double h = reducePrecision(a * 0x1p-1051, 23);
    System.out.println(decompose(h) + " " + h);
}
```

And its output:

```
0 10000000101 0010010001100011000110011111011100100100111000111011 73.0967787376657
0 10000000101 0010010001100011000110100000000000000000000000000000 73.0967788696289
0 10000000101 0010010001100011000110100000000000000000000000000000 73.0967788696289
0 10000000101 0010010001100011000110000000000000000000000000000000 73.09677124023438
0 10000000101 0010010001100011001000000000000000000000000000000000 73.0968017578125
0 11111111110 0010010001100011000110100000000000000000000000000000 1.0266060746443803E308
0 00000000001 0010010001100011000110100000000000000000000000000000 2.541339559435826E-308
0 00000000000 0000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000 2.652494739E-315
```